# Passing parameters to a trait

Tags: scala

I want to model the game of chess.
For that, I want to make an abstract class, `Piece` which takes a player and a position as arguments. From that, I want to extend to other classes such as `Pawn`:

```
trait Piece(player: Int, pos: Pos) = {

  def spaces(destination: Pos): List[Pos]

}

case class Pawn extends Piece = {
//some other code
}
```

However, I think I'm not allowed to pass parameters to a trait, like this `trait Piece(player: Int, pos: Pos)`.

So how can I have an abstract class `Piece` that has fields?

Comment: Use an abstract class instead of a trait

Comment: Scala 3 supports parameters in trait. Check: https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/trait-parameters.html for more details

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use an abstract class

```
abstract class Piece(player: Int, pos: Pos) {
  ...
}

case class Pawn(player: Int, pos: Pos) extends Piece(player, pos)
```

Or (probably better) you define those members abstractly in a trait

```
trait Piece {
  def player: Int
  def pos: Pos
  ...
}

case class Pawn(player: Int, pos: Pos) extends Piece
```

Comment: 2nd solution with trait: using the machinery of the cass class (implicit getter method) for this aspect, clever! Thanks

Comment: and Scala 3.0 brings then the "parameterized traits" as far as I now

Answer (score 10):

[Dotty allows traits to have parameters, just like classes have parameters.](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/trait-parameters.html)

```
trait Greeting(val name: String) {
  def msg = s"How are you, $name"
}

class C extends Greeting("Bob") {
  println(msg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't happy with the accepted answer for my use-case so I did the following. Note that you have two possibilities here for this same approach:

```
trait Piece {
   // these can be referred to within this trait to implement reusable code
   val player: Int 
   val pos: Pos

   def spaces(destination: Pos): List[Pos] = {
     // use player and pos at will e.g.
     List(pos, destination)  
   }
}

case class Pawn(playerArg: Int, posArg: Pos) extends Piece = {
   // now override those with whatever you like
   override val player: Int = playerArg 
   override val pos: Pos = posArg

   //some other code
}
```

The second alternative is to use and override methods instead e.g. `def getPlayer: Int`.

Yet another possibility is to use `implicit` on the trait methods that would require accessing those attributes but I'm not a big fan of this approach.

That said, apparently they have been thinking about it [SIP-25 Trait Parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/trait-parameters.html).